# pjax with internal page target blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, pjax

I'm using pjax on one of my projects. I have a problem with opening a page in a new tab/window.

pjax seems to open all links in the same window except for external website links.

Pjax code

```
$(function(){
  $(document).pjax('a', '.main-header');
});
```

Can anyone tell me what seems to be the problem with url's that have `target="_blank"` and how to fix it? Really appropriate your help.

Comment: So what is your expected output? External links should open in new window?

Comment: i need internal links with `target="_blank"` to be open in a new window

Comment: Can you not do something like : `pjax('a:not(a[target=_blank"])', '.main-header')`?

Comment: @putvande thank you it works like a charm. added `$(document).pjax('a:not(a[target=_blank"])', '.main-header')` can you added as an answer so i can select it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use the selector like this to only select `a` tags that don't have a `target="_blank"`:

```
 $(document).pjax('a:not(a[target="_blank"])', '.main-header')
```